# Overide Php Version on Server with PHP.ini file

Tags: php, apache, joomla, cpanel

I uploaded a Joomla 3.3 website on an Apache server but it showed me a **Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!** error message.
I read that i can change the php version on cPanel -> Software and Services -> PHP configuration. I opened the PHP configuration and it just shows values. So i contacted my Hosting provider, they said the php version is the latest version and that i need to override the php settings using a php.ini file.

1st, if the system is updated as they say it is, should i be seeing that message. 
2nd, how can i change the php version to accommodate my joomla website.

Comment: Changing the version number alone won't solve your issue. If your addon needs a specific version of PHP then you need to have that version (or better) installed.

Comment: But i'm on a shared hosting and the hosting provider told me that they have the latest version of php. I don't understand how i could even face this kind of problem if they had the latest version installed.

Comment: The latest version of PHP (feb 10, 2015) is 5.6.5 http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a problem you should be talking to your hosting provider about.

Comment: Just like i said, the hosting provider told me they have the latest version and they told me to override it myself, they aren't much help. That's why I'm here.

Answer (score 2):

Your hosting provider are not using PHP 5.3.10 or higher version of php and due to that you are getting this issues.

You can check your php version by creating the php info page on your site.

Also you can suggest your hosting provider to install multiple php version on your server so that you can use any php version which you want. They can install it with the ntPHPselector plugins, It's free plugins and it's working good.

Answer (score 0):

If they really have the latest version of php then you can try to use `AddHandler` in your .htaccess file to choose php version.

For example:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

or

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php
```

Depends on hosting configuration.

Comment: I tried both, i added the text on .htaccess file and it didn't work. Instead when i browse to the website, it opens a download dialogue box.